# Overlay text over an image with JQuery and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working overlay text over an image with Jquery and css. Overlay text is showing good on image. But I am trying to change text font and size. I tried to change in css for font family and everything. But it is not effecting anything. Please see what I did code.

In css file:

```
    #container {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.back
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
}
.wrap
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.comment
{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  top:100px;
  left:0px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: white; 
  font-family:"Bookman Old Style", "Book Antiqua", Garamond;  
  font-size:100%;
  background: #4A4D4A;
  padding: 10px;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60);
  -moz-opacity:0.6;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
  opacity: 0.6;
  line-height: 90%
}
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('.wrap').hover(function () {
            $(this).children('.comment').stop().css("top", "0px");
        }
            , function () {
                $(this).children('.comment').stop().animate({ "top": '400px' }, 600);
            });
    });

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <SPSWC:ProfilePropertyImage PropertyName="PictureUrl" ResizeToFit="100" RenderWrapTable="False"
                        ShowPlaceholder="true" ID="PictureUrlImage" runat="server" class="back" />
                    <span class="comment"><a href="http://www.google.com" id="A1"  >Edit Picture </a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now Image is showing like this.

[image]

**But I want show image like FaceBook**

[image]

Gurus please advice me

JSfiddle : jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/7mfj7/1

Comment: If you share a link to the page or setup a jsfiddle we could help you out much more easily.

Comment: What is `SPSWC:ProfilePropertyImage` ?

Comment: I created jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/7mfj7/1/

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what is the resulting HTML. as you seem to be using tags that are being evaluated in serverside such as `SPSWC:ProfilePropertyImage`. You don't even need Javascript to do such things. simple CSS can work. You check the [`Fiddle#d42SU/1/`](http://jsfiddle.net/d42SU/1/) That does the exactly same thing you want. assuming this is the HTML.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="wrap">
       <img src ="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
       <span class="comment">
          <a href="http://www.google.com" id="A1" >Edit Picture </a>
       </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

with CSS

```
#container{
  width: 256px;
}
#container .wrap{
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#container .wrap img{
  position: relative;
}
#container .wrap span.comment{
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
}
#container .wrap:hover span.comment{
  display: block;
}
#container .wrap:hover span.comment a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS3 can do the most of this. It can do the hover effect anyway

**Update**

If your using this on `.wrap` then make sure you make its `position:relative` because then the `:after` can position itself properly.

Try

```
.element:hover:after{
    content: "<a class='edit_picture' href='' title=''>Edit Picture</a>";
    position:absolute;
    width:80px;
    margin-right:-80px;
    left:100%;
    top:0%;
}
```

You do need a little JS though

```
$(function () {
    $('.edit_picture').click(function () {
        //do magic...
    });
});
```